# Android Edit Space Between Text and Images ArrayList

Tags: java, android, android-layout, arraylist, layoutparams

Trying to list text and images in row format and that is displayed in tabs total of 5 now. I am using layout parameters to give padding to each row of text and images but the gap between the text and images is too big.

I can't figure it out how can I edit the space between the text and images with this code I am still learning

[image]

```
public class SkillsActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private Toolbar toolbar;
private ViewPager mPager;
private SlidingTabLayout mTabs;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.skills_layout);

//        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
//        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

    SlidingTabLayout mSlidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
    Integer[] iconResourceArray = { R.drawable.ic_star,
            R.drawable.ic_star, R.drawable.ic_star,
            R.drawable.ic_star, R.drawable.ic_star };
    Integer[] titleResourceArray = { R.string.star_1, R.string.star_2,
            R.string.star_3, R.string.star_4, R.string.star_5 };

    mSlidingTabLayout.setIconResourceArray(iconResourceArray);
    mSlidingTabLayout.setmTtileResourceArray(titleResourceArray);
    mSlidingTabLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
    mSlidingTabLayout.setSelectedIndicatorColors(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
    mSlidingTabLayout.setCustomTabView(R.layout.custom_tab_title, R.id.tabtext, R.id.tabimage);
    mSlidingTabLayout.setViewPager(mPager);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);



    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_whatever) {
        return true;
    }

    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    String[] tabs;


    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        tabs = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tabs);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        MyFragment myFragment = MyFragment.getInstance(position);

        return myFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabs[position];
    }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 5;
    }
}

public static class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String TAB_POSITION_KEY = "TAB_PORITION_KEY";
//
//        public static final int LT = 22;
//        public static final int RB = 22;
//        public static final int RS = 22;
//
//        public static String SEPARATOR = " + ";

    private ListView mainListView;

    public static MyFragment getInstance(int position) {
        MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(TAB_POSITION_KEY, position);
        myFragment.setArguments(args);
        return myFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my, container, false);

        Bundle bundel = getArguments();
        int position = bundel.getInt(TAB_POSITION_KEY);
        ArrayList<ListItem> collection = new ArrayList<ListItem>();

        mainListView = (ListView) layout.findViewById(R.id.mainListView);

        String[] itemTitle = {};

        switch (position) {
            case 0:

                ListItem.LT_RES_ID = R.drawable.trigger02;
                ListItem.RS_RES_ID = R.drawable.trigger02;

                itemTitle = new String[]{
                         ListItem.TEXT_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + "Ball Juggle (while standing) - Hold " + ListItem.SEPARATOR_0
                        + ListItem.IMAGE_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + ListItem.LT_RES_ID + ListItem.SEPARATOR_0
                        ,

                        ListItem.TEXT_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + "Ball Juggle (while standing) - Hold " + ListItem.SEPARATOR_0
                    + ListItem.IMAGE_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + ListItem.RS_RES_ID + ListItem.SEPARATOR_0
                    + ListItem.TEXT_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + "Tap" + ListItem.SEPARATOR_0
                    +ListItem.IMAGE_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + ListItem.RS_RES_ID,};
//                    itemPictures = new Integer[]{LT, RB};
                break;
            case 1:
                itemTitle = new String[]{
                        ListItem.TEXT_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + "Ball Juggle (while standing) - Hold " + ListItem.SEPARATOR_0
                                + ListItem.IMAGE_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + ListItem.LT_RES_ID + ListItem.SEPARATOR_0
                                + ListItem.TEXT_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + " + Tap " + ListItem.SEPARATOR_0
                                +ListItem.IMAGE_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + ListItem.LT_RES_ID
                                + ListItem.TEXT_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + " + Tap " + ListItem.SEPARATOR_0
                                +ListItem.IMAGE_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + ListItem.LT_RES_ID,

                        ListItem.TEXT_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + "Ball Juggle (while standing) - Hold " + ListItem.SEPARATOR_0
                                + ListItem.IMAGE_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + ListItem.LT_RES_ID + ListItem.SEPARATOR_0
                                + ListItem.TEXT_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + " + Tap " + ListItem.SEPARATOR_0
                                +ListItem.IMAGE_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + ListItem.RS_RES_ID,
                        ListItem.TEXT_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + "Ball Juggle (while standing) - Hold " + ListItem.SEPARATOR_0
                                + ListItem.IMAGE_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + ListItem.RS_RES_ID + ListItem.SEPARATOR_0
                                + ListItem.TEXT_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + " + Tap " + ListItem.SEPARATOR_0
                                +ListItem.IMAGE_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + ListItem.LT_RES_ID,

                        ListItem.TEXT_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + "Ball Juggle (while standing) - Hold " + ListItem.SEPARATOR_0
                                + ListItem.IMAGE_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + ListItem.LT_RES_ID + ListItem.SEPARATOR_0
                                + ListItem.TEXT_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + " + Tap " + ListItem.SEPARATOR_0
                                +ListItem.IMAGE_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + ListItem.RS_RES_ID,
                        ListItem.TEXT_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + "Ball Juggle (while standing) - Hold " + ListItem.SEPARATOR_0
                                + ListItem.IMAGE_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + ListItem.LT_RES_ID + ListItem.SEPARATOR_0
                                + ListItem.TEXT_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + " + Tap " + ListItem.SEPARATOR_0
                                +ListItem.IMAGE_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + ListItem.RS_RES_ID,

                        ListItem.TEXT_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + "Ball Juggle (while standing) - Hold " + ListItem.SEPARATOR_0
                                + ListItem.IMAGE_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + ListItem.RS_RES_ID + ListItem.SEPARATOR_0
                                + ListItem.TEXT_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + " + Tap " + ListItem.SEPARATOR_0
                                +ListItem.IMAGE_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + ListItem.RS_RES_ID,};
                break;
            case 2:
                itemTitle = new String[]{
                        ListItem.TEXT_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + "Ball Juggle (while standing) - Hold " + ListItem.SEPARATOR_0
                                + ListItem.IMAGE_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + ListItem.LT_RES_ID + ListItem.SEPARATOR_0
                                + ListItem.TEXT_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + " + Tap " + ListItem.SEPARATOR_0
                                +ListItem.IMAGE_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + ListItem.RS_RES_ID,

                        ListItem.TEXT_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + "Ball Juggle (while standing) - Hold " + ListItem.SEPARATOR_0
                                + ListItem.IMAGE_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + ListItem.RS_RES_ID + ListItem.SEPARATOR_0
                                + ListItem.TEXT_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + " + Tap " + ListItem.SEPARATOR_0
                                +ListItem.IMAGE_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + ListItem.RS_RES_ID,
                        ListItem.TEXT_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + "Ball Juggle (while standing) - Hold " + ListItem.SEPARATOR_0
                                + ListItem.IMAGE_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + ListItem.LT_RES_ID + ListItem.SEPARATOR_0
                                + ListItem.TEXT_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + " + Tap " + ListItem.SEPARATOR_0
                                +ListItem.IMAGE_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + ListItem.RS_RES_ID,

                        ListItem.TEXT_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + "Ball Juggle (while standing) - Hold " + ListItem.SEPARATOR_0
                                + ListItem.IMAGE_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + ListItem.RS_RES_ID + ListItem.SEPARATOR_0
                                + ListItem.TEXT_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + " + Tap " + ListItem.SEPARATOR_0
                                +ListItem.IMAGE_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + ListItem.LT_RES_ID,};
                break;
            case 3:
                itemTitle = new String[]{
                        ListItem.TEXT_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + "Ball Juggle (while standing) - Hold " + ListItem.SEPARATOR_0
                                + ListItem.IMAGE_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + ListItem.LT_RES_ID + ListItem.SEPARATOR_0
                                + ListItem.TEXT_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + " + Tap " + ListItem.SEPARATOR_0
                                +ListItem.IMAGE_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + ListItem.RS_RES_ID,

                        ListItem.TEXT_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + "Ball Juggle (while standing) - Hold " + ListItem.SEPARATOR_0
                                + ListItem.IMAGE_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + ListItem.LT_RES_ID + ListItem.SEPARATOR_0
                                + ListItem.TEXT_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + " + Tap " + ListItem.SEPARATOR_0
                                +ListItem.IMAGE_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + ListItem.RS_RES_ID,
                };
                break;
            case 4:
                itemTitle = new String[]{
                        ListItem.TEXT_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + "Ball Juggle (while standing) - Hold " + ListItem.SEPARATOR_0
                                + ListItem.IMAGE_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + ListItem.LT_RES_ID + ListItem.SEPARATOR_0
                                + ListItem.TEXT_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + " + Tap " + ListItem.SEPARATOR_0
                                +ListItem.IMAGE_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + ListItem.LT_RES_ID,

                        ListItem.TEXT_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + "Ball Juggle (while standing) - Hold " + ListItem.SEPARATOR_0
                                + ListItem.IMAGE_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + ListItem.LT_RES_ID + ListItem.SEPARATOR_0
                                + ListItem.TEXT_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + " + Tap " + ListItem.SEPARATOR_0
                                +ListItem.IMAGE_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + ListItem.RS_RES_ID,
                        ListItem.TEXT_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + "Ball Juggle (while standing) - Hold " + ListItem.SEPARATOR_0
                                + ListItem.IMAGE_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + ListItem.LT_RES_ID + ListItem.SEPARATOR_0
                                + ListItem.TEXT_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + " + Tap " + ListItem.SEPARATOR_0
                                +ListItem.IMAGE_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + ListItem.RS_RES_ID,

                        ListItem.TEXT_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + "Ball Juggle (while standing) - Hold " + ListItem.SEPARATOR_0
                                + ListItem.IMAGE_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + ListItem.RS_RES_ID + ListItem.SEPARATOR_0
                                + ListItem.TEXT_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + " + Tap " + ListItem.SEPARATOR_0
                                +ListItem.IMAGE_VIEW + ListItem.SEPARATOR_1 + ListItem.LT_RES_ID,};
                break;
            default:
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "check tabs position", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        addAll(collection, itemTitle);


        mainListView.setAdapter(new ListViewAdapter(collection));
        return layout;
    }
    private static void addAll(ArrayList<ListItem> items, String[] data) {
        for(String string : data) {
            items.add(new ListItem(string));
        }
    }
}
}
```

Adapter

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private ArrayList<ListItem> mDataset;

public ListViewAdapter(ArrayList<ListItem> myDataset) {
    mDataset = myDataset;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mDataset.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mDataset.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

LinearLayout layout;
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    layout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.textList);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams relativeParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    relativeParams.leftMargin = 50;
    relativeParams.topMargin = 10;
    relativeParams.bottomMargin = 10;
    relativeParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    relativeParams.weight = 1;
//        relativeParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);


    ListItem item = mDataset.get(position);
    View view = item.getNextView(parent.getContext());
    int index = 0;
    while (view != null) {
        layout.addView(view,index++,relativeParams);
        view = item.getNextView(parent.getContext());
    }

    return v;
}
}
```

ListItem

```
public class ListItem {
public String text;

public ListItem(String text) {
    this.text = text;
    viewList = text.split(SEPARATOR_0);
}

/**********************************************************************************************/
public static final String SEPARATOR_0 = ":::::::";
public static final String SEPARATOR_1 = "_separ1";
public static final String TEXT_VIEW = "_56text";
public static final String IMAGE_VIEW = "_23image";
public static final String LT = "LT";
public static final String RS = "RS";

public static int LT_RES_ID = -1;
public static int RS_RES_ID = -2;

private String[] viewList;
private int currentIndex;

public View getNextView(Context context) {
    View result = null;

    if (currentIndex < viewList.length  ) {
        String viewPointer = viewList[currentIndex++];
        int id = -1;
        String[] temp = viewPointer.split(SEPARATOR_1);
        if (temp[0].startsWith(TEXT_VIEW)) {
            result = new TextView(context);
            ((TextView)result).setText(temp[1]);//TODO: might be NPE
        } else if (temp[0].startsWith(IMAGE_VIEW)) {
            result = new ImageView(context);

            if (temp[1].equals("" + LT_RES_ID)) {
                id = LT_RES_ID;
            } else if (temp[1].equals("" + RS_RES_ID)) {
                id = RS_RES_ID;
            } else {
                id = LT_RES_ID;
            }

            ((ImageView)result).setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(id));//TODO: might be NPE
        } else {
            Log.e("ListItem::getNextView()", "unknown view internal identificator");
        }
    }

    return result;
}
}
```

Layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/textList"
android:background="@color/colorDivider">


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try to decrease the value of `relativeParams.leftMargin = 50;`